# Listbox Values calculate

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

This resets the text box for quantity and amount to zero when i test, how do i make this calculate?

```
Dim Number As Integer

txtNumber.Text = Number

Dim orchestra As Integer = 40
Dim mezz As Integer = 27.5
Dim general As Integer = 15
Dim balcony As Integer = 10

If lstSection.SelectedItem = "Orchestra" Then
  txtAmount.Text = (Number * 40)
ElseIf lstSection.SelectedItem = "Mezzanine" Then
  txtAmount.Text = (Number * 27.5)
ElseIf lstSection.SelectedItem = "General" Then
  txtAmount.Text = (Number * 15)
ElseIf lstSection.SelectedItem = "Balcony" Then
  txtAmount.Text = (Number * 10)
End If
```

Comment: maybe you need `Dim Number = Val(txtNumber.Text)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming my edit is correct, and you intend to declare your `Number` variable within the same method, the problem you're seeing is occurring because you're not assigning a value to `Number`.

`Integer` value types always initialize with the default value of `0`.

Thus: `txtAmount.Text = (0 * 40)`, which of course will always be `0`.